# CSS issue in 2 difference android versions.(4.1.2 and 4.4.2)

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am facing issue like one of my samsung device display correct css and another samsung device does not.

in right side of images(android version 4.1.2) and left side (android version 4.4.2) the problem in 4.1.2 device.

any solution for this or any BUG in android version.

i apply ( .platform-android4_1{} ) css also but can't effect.

example(Header and buttons are smaller,badges are small)

help me please .

thank you[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of ionic android developers face this issue because of different verions of web-views environment on different devices. Solution of this is to add [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) plugin to your project.This makes your Cordova / Ionic application use the Crosswalk WebView instead of the System WebView. It patches own browser with application so it runs in that having same specific environment on each device. So application behavior will be same on each device.
add this plugin using following command:
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` 
More about Crosswalk, see link : https://crosswalk-project.org 
Read [this blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/) by ionic to understand how it helps you stablize and improve behavior of hybrid applications across all versions of android.

Comment: do let me know if this fixes your issues.

Comment: its work but one drwaback is we need to pre-install crosswalk apk then and then my apk runs perfectly

Comment: :( is there any solution to Embedding crosswalk with our apk?

Comment: because of crosswalk so many functionality stops. :( like icons are hide update location stops etc. and so many drawbacks first think and then go ahead for crosswalk....